# Nested IF Condition for ignore blanks

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to create a condition using Nested if's with below formula to calculate the timeliness of work done

```
=IF(AND(OR(G2="First Time Right",A2<=B2),C2<=B2, D2<=TIME(15,0,0),E2<=B2, F2="Completed", NOT(ISBLANK(E2=""))), "MET", "NOT MET")
```

and i'm trying to include another if condition for blank cells

if C2, E2, E3 is blank then write cell as blank instead of MET or NOT MET

if condition formula works seperately  `=if(not(isblank(C2:E2="", "")`, i'm trying to add these as nested to my existing formula, so that at last if all these C2 to E2, cells are blank, it should write blank.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you formula is working for everything but blank cells you can use the following:

```
=IF(OR(C2="",E2="",E3=""),"", <your formula>)
```

or if all the cells need to be blank instead of just one

```
=IF(AND(C2="",E2="",E3=""),"", <your formula>)
```

Just laying out your original formula for easier reading.  Basically putting each logical check of your AND statement on its own line.

```
=IF(AND(
        OR(G2="First Time Right",A2<=B2),
        C2<=B2,
        D2<=TIME(15,0,0),
        E2<=B2,
        F2="Completed"
        ), "MET", "NOT MET")
```

This is a little easier to read.  I wound up deleting your ISBLANK condition, and removed what appeared to be some excess ).

```
=IF(AND(OR(G2="First Time Right",A2<=B2), C2<=B2, D2<=TIME(15,0,0), E2<=B2, F2="Completed" ), "MET", "NOT MET")
```

If this adjust formula works for you. then your final formula would look like the following:

```
=IF(OR(C2="",E2="",E3=""),"", IF(AND(OR(G2="First Time Right",A2<=B2), C2<=B2, D2<=TIME(15,0,0), E2<=B2, F2="Completed" ), "MET", "NOT MET"))
```

Change the OR to an AND depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked as expected. I replaced with AND as you said based on my requirement =IF(
AND(C2="",D2="",E2=""),"",
IF(
AND(
OR(G2="First Time Right",A2<=B2),
C2<=B2,
D2<=TIME(15,0,0),
E2<=B2,
F2="Completed"
),"MET","NOT MET"))